# Replace variable in string with Regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm new to Regex and Notepad++ need to remove variables from code. 
For example, remove everything between the double quotes in lines like this:
alt=""Frontline Plus for Dogs and Cats""

To leave me with alt=""""

I know it's probably simple, but I couldn't find any answers that made sense to me. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Remove everything between the double quotes

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `alt="".*?""`
- Set "Replace with" to `alt=""""`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
alt=""Frontline Plus for Dogs and Cats""
alt=""Frontline Plus for Dogs and Cats""
alt=""Frontline Plus for Dogs and Cats""
```

**After**:

```
alt=""""
alt=""""
alt=""""
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)